# Get the size of data and code regions for a binary file

Tags: c++, c, unix

I have a binary executable file "foo". Using a C program in unix, is it possible to retrieve the size of code and data regions for the file foo?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I write something that does what `size` does?" or are you looking for `size`?

Comment: It would like to know, how to write something what size does. Using some predefined or user-defined function call, I want to get the size of code and data regions as return values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`size`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?size) command for this.

#### man `size`

> The GNU size utility lists the section sizes and the total size for each of the object or archive files objfile in its argument list. By default, one line of output is generated for each object file or each module in an archive.

Example:

```
$ size a.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1863     288       8    2159     86f a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends on your platform. On Linux, you can use

`objdump -h foo`

to get the size of each "region".